# Quick reminder about asymptotes of piecewise functions

Tags: calculus

it has been a while since doing calculus. I just need a reminder about vertical asymptotes. If I have 
$$
 f(x) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill \frac{\cos(x)}{x}    \hfill & \text{ if $x\ne0$} \\
      \hfill 1 \hfill & \text{ if $x=0$} \\
  \end{cases}
$$
Clearly, the first piece has a vertical asymptote at $x=0$ (the limit as $x$ tends to $0$ is $\pm \infty$ depending on the side). So even though $f$ is defined for $x=0$, it doesn't change the fact that $f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote there, right? That is, we can't simply define our way out of a vertical asymptote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your function:

[image: asympototes]

Your asymptotes are still there as suspected. I think this confirms your suspicion. The asymptotes haven't been defined away.

Answer (score 2):

The function is, for all intents and purposes, the same. The area under the curve from 0 to 1 is still not convergent, and the function is not differentiable at $x=0$ (as the limit of the value is still $\pm\infty,$ but the value at the point is 1, implying discontinuity). Depending on what you consider a vertical asymptote, it may or may not have one. The limit is still $\pm\infty$ depending on the side you approach from, a common definition for a vertical asymptote, but the value of x is defined, so the function is defined on the y axis. Assuming you go with the conventional definition that an asymptote "is a line such that the distance between the curve and the line approaches zero as they tend to infinity" (Wikipedia), then I would say the answer is yes - the asymptote still exists

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seemed I even answered my question by mentioning that the limit went to $\infty$. It helped to see you write it down though.